# Angular Installation

Tags: release-juno, software-installation

I'm trying to install npm and angular but when I do I get this error, any help is really appreciated because I need this for a job I start on thursday.

```
rr:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tigerite/kernel/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/tigerite/kernel/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
Error executing command, exiting
```

Comment: That repository doesn't hold releases for `bionic` on which Elementary 5.0 is based.
If you don't mind me asking, why do you need this repo for nodejs and Angular?